# Can't find iccube $Monitoring Cube

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I understood from [icCube release notes](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/release_notes.php) that there is a `$Monitoring` Cube...

I cannot see it anywhere (not in the report designer nor in the MDX IDE...

Where should it be? in a `$Monitoring` schema?

Is there something to set up to make it available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $Monitoring schema is activated via a configuration settings within the file icCube.xml:

> ```
> <monitoringConfigurations>
>     <counters>
>         <activated>true</activated>
>         ...
> ```

Then you need to log in with a user with "administrator" role.

Hope that helps.